Issue with setting up SMTP in Formbricks on Docker - {"error":"Signup disabled"}
I've followed the guides here:

https://formbricks.com/docs/self-hosting/docker
https://formbricks.com/docs/self-hosting/configuration

Everything works fine excepts when I try to set it up to use SMTP services.
When i load the app for the very first time and input my names, email and password on the signup page - it doesn't allow me to create the user and proceed - I get the error {"error":"Signup disabled"}
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.9'
services:
  formbricks:
    image: formbricks/formbricks:latest
    container_name: formbricks
    ports:
      - "8100:3000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://formbricks_user:xxx@formbricks_db:1234/formbricks?schema=public"
      NEXTAUTH_URL: "https://forms.mywebsite.com"
      CRON_SECRET: "c75a4bafa400faad400f90cacab6c0731926bdf046d3db20d36e5da062d77974"
      ENCRYPTION_KEY: "121e84bbf1d68af06a20bf103ede8caadc0ed9756c557284146cd887c09ca6e3"
      NEXTAUTH_SECRET: "5fca562adea78c315b7181f7901758a19e2c491cee58e2b905f0d080e78826ae"
      WEBAPP_URL: "https://forms.mywebsite.com"
      PORT: 3000
      MAIL_FROM: "forms@mywebsite.com"  # Your email address
      SMTP_HOST: "mail.your-server.de"  # SMTP server address
      SMTP_PORT: "465"  # Port number - Hetzner Server SSL on 465
      SMTP_USERNAME: "internal@mywebsite.com"  # SMTP username
      SMTP_PASSWORD: "111xxxXXX111"  # SMTP password
      SMTP_SECURE_ENABLED: 1
      EMAIL_VERIFICATION_DISABLED: 0  # 0 to Enable email verification
      PASSWORD_RESET_DISABLED: 1  # 0 to Enable password reset functionality
      SMTP_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED_TLS: 1 # If set to 0, the server will accept connections without requiring authorization from the list of supplied CAs
      EMAIL_AUTH_DISABLED: 0 # 0 to Enable
    depends_on:
      - formbricks_db
    networks:
      - formbricks_net

I've tried all kinds of variations of the SMTP-related environment variables, and each time it fails with the same issue.
The only way I've been able to get the formbricks running so far is without SMTP and setting these two:
      EMAIL_VERIFICATION_DISABLED: 1  # 0 to Enable email verification
      PASSWORD_RESET_DISABLED: 1  # 0 to Enable password reset functionality


This way I'm allowed to register, login and do stuff - but there's a clear message when it comes to invite organization members which says:


"SMTP not configured - Invitations cannot be sent at this time because the email service is not configured. You can copy the invite link in the organization settings later."
Obviously I'm trying to have exactly the opposite - email service to be available.

Please help
